# Add Extension function in kotlin to all classes

Tags: kotlin, extension-methods, kotlin-extension

Is it possible to add extension function to all classes? I was thinking about adding it to some common base class like Object. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

With Kotlin, `Any` is the super type like `Object` for Java.

```
fun Any.myExtensionFunction() {
    // ...
}
```

And if you want to support null-receiver too:

```
fun Any?.myExtensionFunction() {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It depends on whether you want to use the type of the object in the signature (either in another argument, or in the return type). If not, use `Any(?)` as Kevin Robatel's answer says; but if you do, you need to use generics, e.g. (from the standard library)

```
inline fun <T, R> T.run(block: T.() -> R): R

inline fun <T> T.takeIf(predicate: (T) -> Boolean): T?
```

etc.